# Cannot render Vue component in my unit test with Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I'm trying to render a component in my Vue unit test with Jest, but I can't seem to get it to work.

The logs say: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

I've tried other components, and it works fine.

**ErrandsListTable.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div
    v-if="!error"
    class="flex-table flex-table--white-background flex-table--green-header flex-table--with-dropdown"
    :class="{ loading: loading }"
  >
    <div class="flex-table__row flex-table--header text--level-6">
      <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3">
        {{ statusHeader }}
      </div>
      <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3">
        {{ idHeader }}
      </div>
      <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-7">
        {{ descriptionHeader }}
      </div>
      <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-5">
        {{ typeHeader }}
      </div>
      <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3">
        {{ dateOpenedHeader }}
      </div>
      <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3">
        {{ dateClosedHeader }}
      </div>
      <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-1" />
    </div>

    <div
      v-for="(errand, index) in sliceArray(errands)"
      :key="!errand.id ? index : errand.id"
    >
      <div
        class="flex-table__row"
        :class="{ 'flex-table__row--closed': index !== selectedErrand }"
        @click="toggleExpanded(index)"
      >
        <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3">
          {{ errand.status }}
        </div>
        <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3">
          {{ errand.id }}
        </div>
        <div
          class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-7 flex-table__cell--show-on-mobile"
          :data-header="descriptionHeader"
        >
          {{ errand.description }}
        </div>
        <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-5">
          {{ errand.type }}
        </div>
        <div
          class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3 flex-table__cell--show-on-mobile"
          :data-header="dateOpenedHeader"
        >
          {{ errand.orderDate }}
        </div>
        <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3">
          {{ errand.deliveryDate }}
        </div>
        <div
          class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-1 flex-table__cell--dropdown-show-on-mobile"
        >
          <i
            class="icon-angle__small"
            :class="{ 'icon-angle__small--down': selectedErrand === index }"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <ErrandsListDetails
        v-if="selectedErrand >= 0 && selectedErrand === index"
        :errand="errand"
        v-bind="$props"
      />
    </div>

    <div
      v-if="errands.length >= numberOfErrandsLoaded"
      class="flex-table--load-more text--level-5"
    >
      <a href="#" @click="loadMore">
        {{ showMoreText }}
        <i class="icon-down" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div
      v-if="errands.length < 1 && !loading"
      class="flex-table--error text--level-5"
    >
      {{ noCasesText }}
    </div>
    <div v-if="error && !loading" class="flex-table--error text--level-5">
      {{ errorText }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from "lodash";
import ErrandsListDetails from "./ErrandsListDetails.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    ErrandsListDetails: ErrandsListDetails
  },
  props: {
    componentTitle: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "";
      }
    },
    showMoreText: {
      type: String,
      default: "Visa fler ärenden"
    },
    statusHeader: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Status";
      }
    },
    dateOpenedHeader: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Beställt/Anmält";
      }
    },
    dateClosedHeader: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Beräknad klar";
      }
    },
    idHeader: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Ärendenummer";
      }
    },
    descriptionHeader: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Beskrivning";
      }
    },
    typeHeader: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Typ";
      }
    },
    fileDetails: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Ladda ned beställningen som PDF:";
      }
    },
    commentsDetails: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Noteringar";
      }
    },
    wordList: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "";
      }
    },
    attachment: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "";
      }
    },
    noCasesText: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Det finns inget att visa";
      }
    },
    errorText: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Något gick fel";
      }
    },
    createdOnFallback: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "-";
      }
    },
    closedOnFallback: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "-";
      }
    },
    errandsCounter: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {
        return null;
      }
    },
    errands: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => {
        return null;
      }
    },
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: () => {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedErrand: -1,
      error: undefined,
      numberOfErrandsLoaded: 10
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleExpanded: function(index) {
      this.selectedErrand = this.selectedErrand === index ? -1 : index;
    },

    loadMore: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.numberOfErrandsLoaded += 10;
    },

    sliceArray: function(array) {
      let val = _.orderBy(array, "orderDate", "desc");
      return val.slice(0, this.numberOfErrandsLoaded);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Also ignore the fact that this component isn't done and might not necessarily involve the most relevant use cases for unit tests. I'm just curious to know why this certain component can't be loaded as a Vue instance in my test?

```js
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import ErrandsListTable from "../ErrandsListTable.vue";

let wrapper;

describe("Errandslist table", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(ErrandsListTable);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.destroy();
  });
  it("is a Vue instance", () => {
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Has anyone had the same issue? If so, can someone explain to me how you solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template  your`errands` array is null, so you cannot access length property. You either have to handle this case in your component or you have to pass this property to the component.

**set default value**

```
errands: {
  type: Array,
  default: () => {
    return [];
  }
}
```

**pass default value during test**

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(ErrandsListTable, {
  propsData: {
    errands: []
  }
})
expect(wrapper.props().errands.length).toBe(0)
```

Comment: Ah I can see it now! Thanks you for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The default value of `errands` prop is `null`. Since you're mounting your component without any props, the default value of `null` takes effect. Your template has `errands.length`, which results in the error you've observed.

To resolve the error, you could either mount the component with an array for the `errands` [prop](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/props.html#props):

```js
wrapper = shallowMount(ErrandsListTable, {
  propsData: {
    errands: []
  }
});
```

...or change the default value from `null` to an empty array:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    errands: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  }
}
```

...or add a conditional (i.e., `v-if="errands"`) to your template so that it is only dereferenced when truthy:

```html
<div v-if="errands && errands.length >= numberOfErrandsLoaded">
           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The last solution is [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) that would protect against users passing in a `null`/`undefined` prop, causing the same error you're encountering.